# Reference Project vs Reference DLL in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am running into a very strange problem and I would like to understand what is happening.
I have a solution with 30 projects and all it is working fine except one of them.
This project has a dependency on another project in the same solution. Adding a Project reference, looks fine in the editor (no red lines etc) but when compiling I get compiler error as if the reference is not there. However if I go and Add Reference directly on the DLL which the project generates then it works fine. I double check and in both scenarios it references the exact same DLL. Why it wouldn't work as a project reference? 
Any ideas welcome !

Comment: Have you tried removing all references pertaining to that project and re-adding them? This sometimes works.

Comment: Make sure your referenced project is compiling, separately.

Comment: @SamLeach I have tried that multiple times. I even deleted everything from the disk in case something somewhere got corrupted but still same issue.

Comment: @Habib It compiles just fine separately that's why I can just reference the DLL directly and then it works. But still I want to understand why this is happening.

Comment: @koumides check the project type. If it is Client profile change it to use .net famework 4.

Comment: Please have a look at the configuration manager. All Projects should have the same target platform (x86, x64 or AnyCPU) and Debug/Release

Comment: @EhsanUllah That would break it for direct referencing as well.

Comment: @joe Checked both. The project is .NET 3.5

Comment: @koumides: Just to be sure: not the target FRAMEWORK, i pointed to target PLATFORM...

Comment: Did you check the project build order ?

Comment: Did you try to `Rebuild` the solution or `Clean` then `Build`?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Yes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the project was different from the name of the folder was under. 
Not sure it had something to do with that when using it as project reference but renaming the project folder fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Project build order is a ratty problem to solve and MSBuild certainly does drop the ball sometimes.  There isn't anything in the question that helps us help you find the root cause.

The simple solution is to help MSBuild and just be explicit about it.  Right-click the project that doesn't build correctly and select "Project Dependencies".  Tick the ones that need to built first.  Also note the Build Order tab in that same dialog, it shows you in what order the projects are going to get built.  Make sure it is now a happy order.

Also note that it is technically possible to create a circular dependency.  It isn't simple to do, it requires incrementally changing the projects and adding references to existing DLLs.  In other words, what you did and shouldn't have done :)  You diagnose that with Build + Clean and never succeeding in building the solution again.

Comment: I doubt this is the issue. Looking at the output of the dependency is compiling without an issue hence I can see the DLL which I can add as a reference and that works.

Comment: I don't know if you have that issue, you didn't document your question nearly well enough.  Setting the project dependency explicitly is the intended solution.

Answer (score 0):

When I've run into issues like this I've generally fixed them by one of two things...

1. Close VS and re-open the solution.  It sometimes "get's confused" about references
2. Remove project references and re-add

Comment: Tried both multiple times but no much luck...The same issue occurred in a colleagues PC as well.

Comment: I thought for sure that would be it since I've run across that problem multiple times.  I'll see if I can come up with something else to try.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be referencing the latest build of the said DLL. The direct DLL reference will not force that DLL to be rebuilt, but a project reference will. Sometimes VS does not report dependency DLL build errors clearly, so it could well be that there is an error in the latest code for the DLL and one you are linking to is an old one. Try looking at the output window (as opposed to the errors list) for detail on why it won't build.

Comment: The reference project is always build without an issue. I checked it multiple times.

Comment: Do you get any errors in amongst the build log in the output window, when it is referenced as a project? When this happens to me there is usually one crucial error hidden somewhere and then a cascade of referencing errors afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend editing the project file and taking a look at what each reference is actually pointing at. Also, check the configuration manager and make sure that the 'problem' project is being included when being build for the particular platform \ configuration you are building against.
'

Comment: I'm not sure why I got downvoted here but you can open the project file to verify where your hard references are pointing to and you can look at the configuration manager to verify that all expected project dependencies are being built.

Comment: No I can't understand the downvote either... it seems that someone has taken a dislike to this question and every answer and downvoted everything. I shall upvote to cancel it out.

Comment: And I have returned the favor.

Answer (score 0):

Both projects are in the same solution? If yes, you might want to check the build order for them, make sure the referenced one is build before the one that references it. Also there is a bug in the MSBuild maybe this will solve your problem :  [solution to MSBuild error](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/12/21/incorrect-solution-build-ordering-when-using-msbuild-exe.aspx)